# Positioning of text and bitmap in a Canvas in OpenStreetMap

Tags: android

i work on an Android-App which uses the osmdroid API to draw some things on the map. I want to draw a picture on the map as well as a text which should be exactly over the picture. But there is the problem, when i draw my bitmap on the map und then the text, the text is on a completely other place than the picture.

```
@Override
protected void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapview, boolean bool) {
    final Projection pj = mapview.getProjection();
    pj.toMapPixels(this.location, coordinates);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.context.getResources(), R.drawable.overlay);  

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawText("BLA", 0, 0, new Paint());
}
```